# Custom Validation in Gin framework

Tags: go

I have an application written with golang `gin framework`. I want to write a middleware to customize all error messages specially in the case of `BindJSON`.

Here is the middleware:

```
func Errors() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        c.Next()
        // Only run if there are some errors to handle
        if len(c.Errors) > 0 {
            for _, e := range c.Errors {
                // Find out what type of error it is
                switch e.Type {
                case gin.ErrorTypePublic:
                    // Only output public errors if nothing has been written yet
                    if !c.Writer.Written() {
                        c.JSON(c.Writer.Status(), gin.H{"Error": e.Error()})
                    }
                case gin.ErrorTypeBind:
                    errs := e.Err.(validator.ValidationErrors)
                    list := make(map[int]string)

                    fmt.Println(errs)
                    for field, err := range errs {
                        list[field] = validationErrorToText(err)
                    }
                    // Make sure we maintain the preset response status
                    status := http.StatusBadRequest
                    if c.Writer.Status() != http.StatusOK {
                        status = c.Writer.Status()
                    }
                    c.JSON(status, gin.H{"Errors": list})

                default:
                    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"Errors": c.Errors.JSON()})
                }

            }
            // If there was no public or bind error, display default 500 message
            if !c.Writer.Written() {
                c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"Error": errorInternalError.Error()})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The functionality is so simple, it gets all the `gin` errors and do something based on error type! the problem is in case of `gin.ErrorTypeBind` when i've tried to map errors to validation errors: `e.Err.(validator.ValidationErrors)`. 
I've got this error

`interface conversion: error is validator.ValidationErrors, not validator.ValidationErrors (types from different packages)`

here is the list of imported packages:

```
import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [source code of gin](https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin/blob/cdd02fa9d65c15de42f1a4522fcb9af28fe56cf9/binding/default_validator.go) I am seeing this:

```
import (
    "gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v8"
)
```

but you are using `"gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9"`